# ImportError: cannot import name 'Maca' from partially initialized module 'maca.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django, web

I have this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Maca' from partially initialized module 'maca.models' (most likely due to a circular import)`.

I have code like this

```
from maca.models import Maca
class Maca2(models.Model)
   maca = models.ForeignKey(
     Maca, on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

Now to model "Maca" I'm trying to access every single "Maca2" objects like this

```
from maca2.models import Maca2
class Maca(models.Model)
  ...


@property
maca_has_maca2(self)
  maca2 = Maca2.objects.filter(maca=self.id)
```

Can you help me to handle this?

Comment: You can use the reverse relationship to access the related instances from a ForeignKey, you don't need to import the model: `maca2 =  self.maka2_set.all()`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the `Maca2` in the `maca_has_maca2` property:

```
# no import of maca2.models

class Maca(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def maca_has_maca2(self):
        from maca2.models import Maca2
         maca2 = Maca2.objects.all()
```

For `ForeignKey`s, `OneToOneField`s and `ManyToManyField`s, you can make use of a string literal with as structure `'app_name.ModelName'` to refer to a model, for example:

```
# no import of maca2.models

class Maca(models.Model):
    maca2 = models.ForeignKey(
        'maca2.Maca2', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

This avoids importing modules and thus circular imports. If the model has the same `app_name`, you can reference this by *`'ModelName'`*.

Comment: Should probably also note that `ForeignKey`s can use string references to model labels.